# Python: (partial) matching elements of a list to DataFrame columns, returning entry of a different column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I am a beginner in python and have encountered the following problem: I have a long list of strings (I took 3 now for the example):

```
ENSEMBL_IDs = ['ENSG00000040608',
               'ENSG00000070371',
               'ENSG00000070413']
```

which are *partial* matches of the data in column 0 of my DataFrame `genes_df` (first 3 entries shown):

```
genes_list = (['ENSG00000040608.28', 'RTN4R'],
            ['ENSG00000070371.91', 'CLTCL1'],
            ['ENSG00000070413.17', 'DGCR2'])

genes_df = pd.DataFrame(genes_list)
```

The task I want to perform is conceptually not that difficult: I want to compare each element of `ENSEMBL_IDs` to `genes_df.iloc[:,0]`  (which are partial matches: each element of `ENSEMBL_IDs` is contained within column 0 of `genes_df`, as outlined above). If the element of `EMSEMBL_IDs` matches the element in `genes_df.iloc[:,0]` (which it does, apart from the extra numbers after the period ".XX" ), I want to return the "corresponding" value that is stored in the first column of the `genes_df` Dataframe: the actual gene name, 'RTN4R' as an example.

I want to store these in a list. So, in the end, I would be left with a list like follows:

```
`genenames = ['RTN4R', 'CLTCL1', 'DGCR2']`
```

Some info that might be helpful: all of the entries in `ENSEMBL_IDs` are unique, and all of them are for sure contained in column 0 of `genes_df`.

I think I am looking for something along the lines of:

```
`genenames = []
for i in ENSEMBL_IDs:
    if i in genes_df.iloc[:,0]:
        genenames.append(# corresponding value in genes_df.iloc[:,1])`
```

I am sorry if the question has been asked before; I kept looking and was not able to find a solution that was applicable to my problem.

Thank you for your help!

Thanks also for the edit, English is not my first language, so the improvements were insightful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of the part after the dot (with [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) or [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)) before matching the values with [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
m = genes_df[0].str.extract('([^.]+)', expand=False).isin(ENSEMBL_IDs)
# or
m = genes_df[0].str.replace('\..*$', '', regex=True).isin(ENSEMBL_IDs)

out = genes_df.loc[m, 1].tolist()
```

Or use a regex with [`str.match`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html):

```
pattern = '|'.join(ENSEMBL_IDs)
m = genes_df[0].str.match(pattern)

out = genes_df.loc[m, 1].tolist()
```

Output: `['RTN4R', 'CLTCL1', 'DGCR2']`

Comment: Thank you mozway! That was helpful and solved the problem.